# Magento 2 : Parent product in result on searching child product sku

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, magento2.3.3, search-result

I am using magento version 2.3.3

My requirement is when i search with child product sku (which is visibility none) so parent (configure) product show in search result

*For example*

Parent product Sku = **configursku**

child 1st product sku = **abc**

child 2nd product sku = **xyz**

child 3rd product sku = **pqr**

so requirement is when i search "abc" so its no result found in search
but it should be showing parent product (configursku) in result

any one help here

thanks in advance